# PyQt6: Qt module enums raise AttributeError

Tags: python, enums, pyqt, attributeerror, pyqt6

I need to translate the following code from PyQt5 (It works there) to PyQt6:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'FramelessWindowHint'
```

I've already tried this:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowFlags.FramelessWindowHint)
```

It says:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'WindowFlags'
```

Comment: Please put all your code

Comment: Perhaps a little more code would help.

Comment: See the PyQt5 Docs: [Things to be Aware of - Enums](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#enums). In PyQt5, enum members were available as both attributes of the class/module (e.g. `Qt.FramelessWindowHint`) *and* as attributes of the enum itself (e.g. `Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint`); but in PyQt6, ***only the latter is supported***. It should also be noted that PyQt6 always uses the name of the *enum type* rather than the *flags type* (see e.g. [Qt::WindowFlags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That flag now lives here:

```
QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint
```